# java jasper params static

Tags: java, jasper-reports

My .jrxml file contains 2 text and one param

[image]

Following is my java code for jasper report, When i run the code it creates pdf file but it is always empty any help ?

```
public class TestReport {

    public static void runReport(String reportFile) {
          try{

            Map parameters = new HashMap();
            parameters.put("my_var", "Address Report");

            JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(reportFile);
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
             JasperPrint jsp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters);
             JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jsp, "/home/ireports/test1.pdf");

          }catch(Exception ex) {
             String connectMsg = "Could not create the report " + ex.getMessage() + " " + ex.getLocalizedMessage();
             System.out.println(connectMsg);
          }
       }

     public static void main(String args[]){
         runReport("/home/ireports/report1.jrxml");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this snippet. It will work    ,Here fileName would be the `.jasper`     file compiled version of `.jrxml`

```
       try {
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(
                    fileName,
                    hm,
                    new JREmptyDataSource());
            JRExporter exporter =
            new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(
            JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,
            outFileName);
            exporter.setParameter(
            JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, outFileName);
            print = null;
            exporter = null;
            //JasperViewer.viewReport(print,false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```